# any good way to approximate this non-convex function with convex function?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

There is a non-convex constraint in my optimization problem, which is given by 
$\displaystyle -xy\log\left(1+\frac{z}{xy}\right)$. Obviously, it is neither convex or concave. Is there any good convex approximation method to approximate this function?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried standard techniques as MCormik relaxations, or alpha BB? BTW what is the verse of the inequality and the interval of definition of the variables?

Comment: Thank you for your help. xylog(1+z/xy)>=constant value, 0<=x<=1, 1<=y<=1。

Comment: What is the MCormik relaxation, or alpha BB? any reference?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is particularly helpful in your situation, but you might consider the 'double' Legendre transform.

What I mean is the following: Let $f$ represent your function. I assume $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$, where $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is some suitable domain.

The ***[Legendre transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation)*** of $f$, denoted by $f^{*}$, is the function defined by

\begin{equation}
f^{*}(y) = \sup_{x \in D}(\langle y, x\rangle - f(x))
\end{equation}
where $y$ is any point where the $\sup_{x \in D}(\langle y, x\rangle - f(x)) < \infty$. (The angled brackets $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ represent the inner-product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.)

We can define $f^{**}$ as the Legendre transform of $f^*$. It has the following properties:

- $f^{**}$ is convex.
- $f^{**} \leq f$.
- If $f$ is finite, but not necessarily convex, then $f^{**}$ is its convex envelope (that is, the largest convex function which is smaller than $f$).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Any reference I can read?

Comment: The most well-known book for this sort of material (convex analysis) is [Convex Analysis by RT Rockafellar](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/1815.html). But this may take you far from your original question :)

Comment: My function is f(x,y,z)=x*y*log(1+z/(x*y)). Based on your comments, how can I get the formation for the f*and f**?  In my function 0<=x<=1, 1<=y<=1. According to your comments,  there are countless f*(y), since y is any point.